# SIGSEGV(SEGV_ACCERR) at IOSurfaceClientGetPixelFormat

Tags: ios, ios13, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm getting an occasional `SIGSEGV(SEGV_ACCERR) at IOSurfaceClientGetPixelFormat` crash when sharing a text file via the `UIActivityViewController` (the text file could be several MB). The full stack trace is:

```
0   IOSurfaceClientGetPixelFormat + 0
1   CA::CG::IOSurfaceContext::create_delegate(CGIOSurfaceContextInfo const*, __CFDictionary const*) + 536
2   CGIOSurfaceContextCreate + 208
3   BSUISurfaceWithColorSpaceAndDrawBlock + 500
4   SBFCreateIOSurfaceForImage + 1060
5   -[CKRemoteItemForSending _setPreviewUIImage:] + 76
6   __46-[CKRemoteItemForSending beginPreviewCreation]_block_invoke + 204
7   __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
8   -[NSBlockOperation main] + 80
9   __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__ + 16
10  -[NSOperation start] + 736
11  __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__ + 16
12  __NSOQSchedule_f + 176
13  _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 100
14  _dispatch_client_callout + 12
15  _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp + 408
16  _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 652
17  _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 372
18  _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
19  _pthread_wqthread + 208
20  start_wqthread + 4
```

The `UIActivityViewController` initialization is passing an `NSURL` and is quite rudimentary:

`[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]] applicationActivities:nil];`

The crash appears occasionally, especially when trying to share the file via the Messages app on the iPhone. Any idea of where this may come from?

Comment: Hi @spassas, i see the crash with the same stacktrace as yours. Have you found a fix for that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should print the URL and check it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The URL is correct - the file appears properly on the iOS share sheet and this issue happens occasionally and for some of the available share options